# How to have two independent page counters in a report?

Tags: page-numbering

I have a report where each page is numbered, starting from 1.
Three chapters of this report, however, have an overall 10-page limit. I would like to have a separate page numbering for them, on top of the normal one.

So, in the footer of each page I would still have the normal page numbering, but for the three special chapters, I would like to have something like *"Page-limited section --- Page X of 10"* in the header.

Is it possible?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{First}
  % Here should start the double numbering
  \chapter{Second}
  \chapter{Third}
  % Here should stop the double numbering
  \chapter{Fourth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Well, not really. If I could make a minimal working example, I shouldn't ask, I guess.

Comment: The MWE does not need to solve the question, just give us some code to start with. Which documentclass you use, if you use packages to customise the header/footer. At the moment we know nothing.

Comment: Honestly I think an MWE in this case does not add anything to the question, but it might be just my impression. I added one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try this code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

% normal report page style
\fancypagestyle{normal}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}

\fancypagestyle{special}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[R]{Page limited section --- Page \the\numexpr\value{page}-\pagesuptonow+1\relax\ of 10}%
}

\newcommand{\normalchapter}{%
  \clearpage
  \pagestyle{normal}%
  \chapter
}
\newcommand{\specialchapter}{%
  \clearpage
  \edef\pagesuptonow{\thepage}%
  \pagestyle{special}%
  \chapter
}

\begin{document}

\normalchapter{Normal 1}

\lipsum[1-15]

\specialchapter{Special 1}

\lipsum[1-30]

\specialchapter{Special 2}

\lipsum[31-60]

\normalchapter{Normal 2}

\lipsum[61-90]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of playing with counters:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{everyshi}
\newcounter{pagecnt}[chapter]
\EveryShipout{\stepcounter{pagecnt}}

\newcommand{\pagestart}{%
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{Page %
        \ifnum\thepagecnt=0
            1%
            \addtocounter{pagecnt}{1}%
        \else%
            \arabic{pagecnt}%
        \fi%
        \space of 10 -- \arabic{page}
    }%
}

\newcommand{\pagestop}{\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}}


\begin{document}
  \chapter{First}
  \newpage
  a

  \chapter{Second}

  % Here should start the double numbering
  \pagestart

  \newpage
  a

  \chapter{Third}

  \newpage
  a

  \chapter{Fourth}

  % Here should stop the double numbering
    \pagestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: Changing \thepage is going to affect a lot more than just the footer.